# Want to get the calculated value from all rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, xcode

I have a table consist of more than 20 rows and each row has 3 text field named Rate, minutes and total. calculation is as rate/60 * minutes = total. I want to get total of all 20 rows in another text field Balance that is not a part of table view cell but of view controller. I want to calculate the value in real time and get the addition of total text field named as  Rupees Text field below table view cell [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h2xy.png).I can see on 3 rows on screen and 17 other are down. I get for only 3 text field in row not for all. I h have written this code but can calculate for 3 rows not for all 20. Please do check Thanks in advance. second issue I have used notification to pass string  and it send me the last value in string not the updated one .  Please do check the image

```
import UIKit

class calculationTVC: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate{
  var numberOfItems = 0
  var myTV : UITableView!



  @IBOutlet weak var minutes: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var total: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var rate: UITextField!

  @IBAction func rateChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    //  print(minutes.text, total.text, rate.text)
    ratesischanged()

  }


  public func ratesischanged(){
    let first = Double(rate.text!)
    let second = Double(minutes.text!)
    let third = Double(0)


    if minutes.text?.count == 0{
      total.text = "\(third)"
    }

    if minutes.text?.count == 0{
      //  print("null")
      total.text = "\(third)"
      //   print("got zero")

    }else{

      let output = Double((first!/60) * second!)
      total.text = "\(output)"

      let rows = myTV.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
      var add : Double!
      var c = [Int]()

      for i in 0..<rows{

        let path = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)


        let cell = myTV.cellForRow(at: path) as? calculationTVC



        add = (cell?.total.text as NSString?)?.doubleValue
        //  print(Int(add))
        //print(add)

        if add != nil{

          c += [Int(add)]

          // print(c)

        }

      }


      var sum = 0
      var counter = 0


      // Enter your code below
      while counter < c.count {

        var newValue = c[counter]
        sum += newValue

        counter += 1
        // print(sum, "sum")

      }


      var myString = String(describing: sum)

      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: calculationScreen.notificationName, object: nil, userInfo: ["DataMy": myString ?? ""])
      //print(ar, "new ar")


    }

  }


  func numberOfRows(numberInt : Int,tableView : UITableView){
    numberOfItems = numberInt
    myTV = tableView
  }


}
```

Comment: you mean total of all deposite . Right?

Comment: @RB1509 yes correct on screen we can see only 3 but I have 20 rows and I want to get the total of deposite value. For ex if I make changes also  it should give the updated at the bottom text field rupees

Comment: ok. you print all data into variable c.Right?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand your issue, so hopefully I'm addressing it - getting a total of an *array* where it's (a) a datasource for a `UITableView` that is showing only some values and (b) displaying this total in a `UITextField`. If so, you need to understand how a table view works - it caches cells. So the easiest way to get a "total" from this is to go at the *datasource* or *array*. Get the total value of **it** and either display it as a header/footer, or as you are trying, a text field.

Comment: yes c and then I pass to sum to mystring with notifier

Comment: stored your total of different 20 rows in one array. after apply for loop or any loop and do sum of that

Comment: okay if I dont use notification will that work? if yes please give me a example or link to the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define ***protocol*** on `tableViewCell` and fire it when the `UITextField` on each cell modified, and in your `viewController` implement of delegate:

```
protocol TableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func textViewValueChanged(minutes: String, rate: String, total: String)
}

class calculationTVC: UITableViewCell { // delete UITextFieldDelegate
    weak var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?
    // ... the rest of your code

    @IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: UIButton) { //action of ***Editing Changed*** and connected to all *UITextField*
        //calculate total
        delegate?.textViewValueChanged(minutes: self.minutes, rate: self.rate, total: self.total)
    }
}

class viewController: UIViewController, UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewdataSource, TableViewCellDelegate { //and what you want to implement
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: IndexPath) as? calculationTVC
        cell.delegate = self
        // ... the rest of your code
        return cell
    }

    func textViewValueChanged(minutes: String, rate: String, total: String) {
        var total = 0
        for i in 1...20 {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: i) as? calculationTVC
         total += cell.rate/60 * cell.minutes
        }
        //set your totalLabel
    } 
}
```

Comment: I get error Value of type 'UITableViewCell?' has no member 'rate' I have added this code in view controller file by making a function

Comment: Thank you for answer I have tried but no idea how to trigger it I have defice delagate in cell like this : minutes.delegate = self and added your code in in function but cannot trigger it please post a way to do it

Comment: I checked I can't get proper value for cell is visible on screen but not for those which are at not visible will be created after scorlling

Comment: thank you I tried and it worked. A small question @arash I need to send data to api in this form [{"id":"34","date_list":"2018\/04\/20"}] I tried many solution and question not worked. I tried with JSON encoding default but no resolution it is array containing json dictonoary . any idea ? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can ask this as a new question